# post uri argument with refit

Tags: c#, .net, refit

I have a class that includes a Uri instance.
The class is sent as an argument to REST api

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
}

public interface IRefitExample
{       
    [Post("/api/example")]
    Task<string> Example(SomeClass someClass);
}
```

For some reason the Uri object does not pass correctly with refit.
The Uri absolute url string looks like this on the client side:
`"file:///var/share"`
When it reach to the server it looks like this:
`"/var/share"`

The refit initialization looks like this:

```
var settings = new RefitSettings(new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer());
            _apiRefit = RestService.For<ISomeApi>($"http://localhost:5000", settings);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't understand the problem right but there is no problem with Refit.
In your `RefitSettings` you use `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer()` which serealize Uri object due to `ISerializable` interface implementaion and pass json like this: `{"Uri":"file:///var/share"}` into http request body.

File URI has next format: `file://host/path`. If host is omitted, it is taken to be "localhost", the machine from which the URL is being interpreted. Note that when omitting host, the slash is not omitted (while "file:///foo.txt" is valid, "file://foo.txt" is not, although some interpreters manage to handle the latter).

So URI from your example points to the following path `./var/share` (which is the same as /var/share) on local machine.

This links can be helpful:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Format
- [RFC8089 appendix-A](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089#appendix-A)
- [RFC8089 appendix-D.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089#appendix-D.1)